# "The Club" where Jerry Seinfeld performed

Tags: seinfeld

At the beginning and end of every Seinfeld episode, Jerry performs a bit of stand-up themed alongside the general plot of that particular episode.

Is the club where he performs this stand-up ever identified? If so, what was its name?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This page](https://sites.google.com/site/seinfeldfilmlocations/inspiration) provides info on Seinfeld filming locations and it seems that the club's name is **Catch A Rising Star Comedy Club** located in New York.

> Jerry Seinfeld used to perform stand up at the *Catch A Rising Star
>   Comedy Club*, which is now the *Vudu Lounge* at *1487 1st Avenue*. In the
>   late 90's the club was located at *253 W. 28th Street*, which was seen
>   in the show.

Here is the link to the [website](http://www.catcharisingstar.com/) of the club.